# Shifting Angles using Arctan2

Tags: delphi, math

I am currently building a pathing system for a game. I've recently figured out the whole Arctan2(Y,X) function to help with rotating the player to the next way-point. However after a lot of debugging I found out that the angle system used in-game isn't the same as a normal angle plan.

[image]

So the issue is the Arctan2(Y,X) function returns an angle that is approtate to the "normal" plan see on the right in the link above, But I need to convert that angle into a usable angle for the In-game angle plan... I hope I am explaining this somewhat decently.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you really using `Arctan2` to *shift* angles? :) It seems more like you need to shift angles from one system to another so that you can use the Actan2 function in your particular context. I know I am nitpicking, but learning to be precise when writing mathematical, scientific, and technical texts is worth the effort.

Comment: It is worth also to show coordinates on your system. Seems coordinates there exist apart from claimed angles. [Pic](https://imgur.com/a/cV9r6Qw)  (example of alike system - OX direction is right, OY top, but zero angle is at top and has CW direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your picture, it is clear that the mapping *f* that maps the angle in the left system to a "normal" angle (mod 360) is given by

*f*: α ↦ 270 − α.

Hence, the inverse mapping, *f*⁻¹, is given by

*f*⁻¹: α ↦ 270 − α.

(Clearly, *f* is an involution.)

Comment: Did you notice that the rotation direction flipped from the left system to the right one? I studied math in french, so excuse me if I'm saying something stupid.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout: Yes. That's why there is a minus sign in the mapping. As α increases, 270 − α decreases.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand

Thank you for the response this helped out a lot !